# How to add two or more input layers to QGIS Model Designer "Merge vector layers" algorithm

Tags: qgis

I try to merge two outputs in a QGIS Model Designer model. How can I add two input layers to the Merge vector layer algorithm? There's only one field for input layers (see screenshot). I tried to add "the other" input as dependency. Also i tried to add both inputs there. In none of the versions I tried, the result contained both inputs.
[image: Model designer Screenshot]

It only works for me, when I export the model to python and create a list of the inputlayers.

```
        # Merge vector layers
    layerlist = [outputs['CreateSpatialIndex_clip']['OUTPUT']]
    layerlist.append(outputs['CreateSpatialIndex_difference']['OUTPUT'])

    alg_params = {
        'CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:2056'),
        'LAYERS': layerlist,
        'OUTPUT': parameters['Av_parzellen_oberwallis_lnnichtln']
    }
    outputs['MergeVectorLayers'] = processing.run('native:mergevectorlayers', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    results['Av_parzellen_oberwallis_lnnichtln'] = outputs['MergeVectorLayers']['OUTPUT']
    return results
```